# How do I write an if-statement that excludes users depending on groups?

Tags: ubuntu, if-statement

So in Ubuntu, a program has to start on the start of a shell, if the user who is logged in is in a certain group. Using an if-statement in the /etc/bash.bashrc is what we are trying right now, but we dont know how to form a valid if-statement for this situation.

```
if [ group == familie ]; then
*the program that has to be started*
fi
```

this is our statement so far..

Comment: This can be very tricky. You have to use `groups` to see users' groups and there can be more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use `id`, as its output is easier to parse then `groups`, which might contain spaces (e.g. in cygwin):

```
if [[ $(/usr/bin/id) == *groups*[,=]'20(games)'* ]] ; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Use your group id and name instead of `20` and `games`.

It might be more secure, though, to let the system do the hard work. Just create a script that contains the code to start the desired programme, and make that script runnable only for the group; then just run the script.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this. For example, you could directly parse the `/etc/group` file with `grep`, `cut` and `tr`:

```
grep -E ^$GROUPNAME: /etc/group | cut -d: -f4 | tr , "\n" | grep -E ^$USERNAME$ | wc -l
```

If the output of the previous command is non-zero, then the user is in the group. Obviously you'll need to replace `$GROUPNAME` and `$USERNAME` with your input.